# how to move from standard groups into artboard in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, adobe-photoshop-elements

I have business card that is designed in an old photoshop version. I have two main groups one represents the card's front and the second is the card's back.

That I am using Photoshop 2015 I want to use the new artboard feature. Instead of having two groups, I want to have two artboards to allow me to export my work on the same page.

I created a new workplace document. Then I created two separate art boards. Now, I need to move my groups from the old file into the new file.

When I try to drag and drop a layer or a group of layers into the new art board, I get "Could not complete your request because of a program error."

How can I get my layers from my old file into the new artboard in my new file?

Comment: You should use Indesign or Illustrator for this...

Answer (score 1):

The error message will only appear when you drag groups and layers directly onto the Layers Panel. If you drag them onto the **document canvas**, the message should not appear. Alternatively, you can use **Duplicate Group** command from right-click menu of the groups/layers.

I currently don't have Photoshop CC 2015 installed, but I do recall that I've encountered the same error message in CC 2015. In newer versions like CC 2017/2018, the error message won't appear when you drag groups/layers onto Layers Panel, the action simply creates no effect at all.